# generate Intel compatible x64 bit dll (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, 64-bit, x86-64

I need to create a simple dll that is compiled in x64 bit and is intel compatible. Currently I use VS 2013, I choosed (Release, x64) and the resulted dll is AMD64. Is there any chance to be able to configure the dll processor architecture compatibility for 64 bit dll?
[image]

Comment: Actually that name is correct and will work on Intel processors, just a silly convention (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) ...

Comment: "amd64" is Microsoft's name for a 64-bit DLL that is compatible with Intel processors.  It was AMD that invented the architecture, Intel copied it when they could not get their own 64-bit architecture competitive.  Itanium was a major flop.  None of this is particularly relevant to managed code, you should target AnyCPU so it runs on any architecture.

Comment: Thank you ! I did not know that. Actually the problem that I really have is that the dll is not usable in Microsoft NAV because it is AMD64 and not MSIL. But this is other problem now :). Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use it, X64 AKA AMD64.